# How to finish activity? (jetpack navigation)

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

I have nav graph with number of fragments, say A, B and C. In C, I would like to finish current activity (AA) and jump to new one (BB, separate activity with its own graph).

This is not working (it seems BB starts but at the same time it seems fragment A of AA is resumed from backstack - and I really don't need that):

```
        <action
            android:id="@+id/back"
            app:destination="@+id/mainActivity"
            app:launchSingleTop="true"
            app:popUpTo="@+id/AA-graph-id"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
```

Q.: Using nav components, how to finish AA (without backstack fragments resume) and jump straight to BB?

PS.: I'm not interested in solutions like fragment C does `startActivity(...)+finish()`

Comment: did you get a solution eventually?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can set clearTask to "true" on your action.

Comment: This option is long gone.